# How to define a hierarchal table using EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

In the application I am working on, we have a users table, TblUser. Users within this table may belong to a single, parent user. A parent user may have multiple child users.

This relationship is maintained within a table called TblUserMapping with two columns, ParentUserId and ChildUserId corresponding with the parent's and child's TblUser.Id value. TblUser.Id is an auto-incrementing value.

How can I define this within EF Core, and would it be possible to Insert a ChildUser into TblUser and use the auto-generated Id value to also create a TblUserMapping record?

Right now I have:

```
[Table("TblUser")]
public class TblUser
{
    public TblUser()
    {        
        ChildUsers            = new List<TblUserMapping>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<TblUserMapping> ChildUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual TblUserMapping ParentUser { get; set; }
}

[Table("TblUserMapping")]
public class TblUserMapping
{
    public TblUserMapping()
    {
    }

    public int ChildUserId { get; set; }
    public int ParentUserId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual TblUser ChildUser { get; set; }
    public virtual TblUser ParentUser { get; set; }
}

public class TblUserMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TblUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TblUser> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(e => e.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}

public class TblUserMappingMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.TblUserMapping>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entities.TblUserMapping> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ChildUserId);
        entity.Property(e => e.ChildUserId)
            .IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.ParentUserId)
            .IsRequired();
        
        
        entity.HasOne(e => e.ParentUser)
            .WithMany(e => e.ChildUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentUserId);

        entity.HasOne(e => e.ChildUser)
            .WithOne(e => e.ParentUser)
            .HasForeignKey<TblUser>(e => e.Id);
    }
}
```

But this isn't working as I had hoped when I do:

```
var userInformation = await _context
    .Users
    .Include(entity => entity.ChildUsers)
    .ThenInclude(entity => entity.ChildUser)
    .Where(s => s.UserName == userName)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var ChildUser = new TblUser
{
    UserName = userModel.UserName,
    ParentUser = new TblUserMapping()
    {
        ParentUser = userInfo
    }
};

_context.Users.Add(ChildUser);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Do you need `TblUserMapping` for anything specific? Why not just have a property `Parent` in `TblUser`?

Comment: I might not need it, and that sounds like a better solution, as Andrew also mentioned, if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach navigation properties, and Entity Framework will populate the ids automatically when it creates them. The example you have given *should* work, you might need to show us how you are getting `userInfo` before we can see what's going on.

That being said, instead of keeping a separate mapping table, I would have each child user refer directly to their parent:

```
[Table("TblUser")]
public class TblUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public TblUser Parent { get; set; }    

    // Lazy-loading is not enabled by default in EF Core, so you don't need the 'virtual' keyword
    // Also, if the initialization of a member does not depend on constructor arguments, I
    // prefer this syntax instead of doing it in the constructor
    public ICollection<TblUser> Children { get; set; } = new List<TblUser>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InverseProperty` attribute in your model:

```
[Table("TblUser")]
public class TblUser
{
public TblUser()
{        
    ChildUsers            = new List<TblUserMapping>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("ChildUser")]
public virtual ICollection<TblUserMapping> ChildUsers { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("ParentUser")]
public virtual TblUserMapping ParentUser { get; set; }
}
```

And in other model:

```
[Table("TblUserMapping")]
public class TblUserMapping
{
public TblUserMapping()
{
}

public int ChildUserId { get; set; }
public int ParentUserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ChildUserId")]
public virtual TblUser ChildUser { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentUserId")]
public virtual TblUser ParentUser { get; set; }
 }
```

As you see I defined these relations with attributes that means no need to came in your configuration.